# Visual Studio - The key combination (ctrl+m, ctrl+c) is bound to command (Controller...) which is not currently available

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a new `asp.net MVC 4` web application, using the asp.net [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-controller).
I create a new project selecting ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application. But when I tried to add a new `controller`, first, I didn't find the "Controllers" folder, I created one, and when i tried to add new Controller, I couldn't find that option. I clicked <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> so i got this message: `The key combination (ctrl+m, ctrl+c) is bound to command (Controller...) which is not currently available`

Note that I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Premium.

Does anyone have any idea about this?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be you didn't select the "ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application" template when creating a new project. I just tested: the controller folder is there, even when i selected empty template.

So try this: File -> New -> Project and type in the 'Search installed Templates' searchbox "MVC 4". Select "ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application".

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know what was the issue!! When I created the first project, I also chose the same template. Now, I created a new one, and searched for "MVC 4", and it worked!! Thanks again